# How to compatible datagridview on demand data loading with stored procedure instead of in-line sql

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, datagridview, ondemand

I like to refer a code which i have taken from this url

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The above url shown how we can load data by `datagridview` just on demand means when user scroll and reach a limit then data will load from db. My code is working but now i am in situation that i have to use a stored procedure from SQL Server which is very big and it return data after so many calculation. So I have to customize my code as a result it should be working with stored procedure instead of in-line SQL. From the above link anyone can see full working sample code. I just here highlight 3 routine from where in-line SQL fired to fetch data from db and this routine I need to change and want to call stored procedure from there instead of in-line SQL.

From this one route use in-line sql:

```
public int RowCount
{
            get
            {
                // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
                if (rowCountValue != -1)
                {
                    return rowCountValue;
                }

                if (filters.Trim().ToUpper().IndexOf("WHERE") > -1)
                {
                    filters = filters.ToUpper().Replace("WHERE", string.Empty);
                }

                // Retrieve the row count from the database.
                command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE 1=1 " + (filters.Trim().Length > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty) + filters;
                rowCountValue = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                return rowCountValue;
            }
}
```

This routine too uses in-line SQL:

```
public DataColumnCollection Columns
{
            get
            {
                // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
                if (columnsValue != null)
                {
                    return columnsValue;
                }

                // Retrieve the column information from the database.
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
                columnsValue = table.Columns;
                return columnsValue;
            }
}
```

This routine too

```
public DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage)
{
            // Store the name of the ID column. This column must contain unique  
            // values so the SQL below will work properly. 
            if (columnToSortBy == null)
            {
                columnToSortBy = this.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            }

            if (!this.Columns[columnToSortBy].Unique)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(
                    "Column {0} must contain unique values.", columnToSortBy));
            }

            // Retrieve the specified number of rows from the database, starting 
            // with the row specified by the lowerPageBoundary parameter.
            if (filters.Trim().ToUpper().IndexOf("WHERE") > -1)
            {
                filters = filters.ToUpper().Replace("WHERE", string.Empty);
            }

            command.CommandText = "Select Top " + rowsPerPage + " " +
                CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames + " From " + tableName +
                " WHERE 1=1 AND " + filters + " " + (filters.Trim().Length > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty) + columnToSortBy + " NOT IN (SELECT TOP " +
                lowerPageBoundary + " " + columnToSortBy + " From " +
                tableName + "  WHERE 1=1 " + (filters.Trim().Length > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty) + filters + " Order By " + sortColumn +
                ") Order By " + sortColumn;
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
}
```

Now I want to use a stored procedure in one routine which replace other two routine.

I will develop the stored procedure with a 1st result will return no of rows and second result will return actual data.

This way I am paging in the stored procedure:

```
WHERE [rn] BETWEEN ((@StartIndex-1) * @EndIndex ) + 1 AND (@StartIndex * @EndIndex)
```

Now see the above routine called `SupplyPageOfData` how it is doing paging and tell me how to use `lowerPageBoundary` and `rowsPerPage` as a result I could send those two value in my sp and sp can do the successfully paging.

`rowsPerPage` is fixed that is 16 but `lowerPageBoundary` jump by 16. so calculation is not coming to my mind like how to change code as a result i can send `lowerPageBoundary`  & `rowsPerPage` to stored procedure and with in stored procedure I can form paging line like `WHERE [rn] BETWEEN ((@StartIndex-1) * @EndIndex ) + 1 AND (@StartIndex * @EndIndex)`

Please help me with code and sample. thanks

Comment: ***WHY*** do you want to replace (working) in-line SQL statements with a stored procedure? What benefit do you expect from that?

Comment: as per our requirement now i have to fetch data from calling store proc. the store proc i am going to call there are huge line of code where data calculation done and data dump in 3 temp table and then return data from 3 temp table.

Comment: It's a ***stored*** procedure - a procedure that is ***stored*** inside your SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a "store" ....

Comment: first see the url at top from where u can see whole code and understand how it is working.

Comment: in-line sql doing paging like this way `command.CommandText = "Select Top " + rowsPerPage + " " + CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames + " From " + tableName +" WHERE 1=1 AND " + filters + " " + (filters.Trim().Length > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty) + columnToSortBy + " NOT IN (SELECT TOP " +lowerPageBoundary + " " + columnToSortBy + " From " + tableName + "  WHERE 1=1 " + (filters.Trim().Length > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty) + filters + " Order By " + sortColumn +
") Order By " + sortColumn;` in case of SP i will pass startindex and endindex.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.